# How to array a rope with a texture without a line between each array object?

Tags: rendering, texturing, modifiers

[image][image]

I'm still beginner in blender, I make a rope and I unwrap it but when I imported a texture to that rope and added an array modifier to make it more longer to use it in a ship then I discovered that line of every array's number
how to solve it ?

Comment: could you please share your object (don't forget to pack the image)?

Comment: Is your texture tiled ?

Comment: either the texture is not repeatable or the UV is not correctly put, hard to say without the file + image

Comment: thanks but idk how to share the file in here

Comment: [How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)

Comment: @tony.miclt22 Use https://blend-exchange.com/ ... You'll need to copy paste the URL of this page, upload your file, then share the URL it will generate